# How to Store Nicknames in Database Table

Tags: database-design, normalization

I need to be able to look up the possible "nicknames" for a given first name, but can't quite figure out the right way to store them.

For example, let's say that all of the following are forms of the same name:

```
Elizabeth, Eliza, Bessie, Beth, Betsy, Betty, Libby, Liza, Lisa, Liz, Lizzie
```

If the user types in "Beth", I would like to be able to retrieve all of the other nicknames in this "set".

Using 20 (or more!) columns called `"Nickname1, Nickname2,..."` seems like a really bad idea.

On the other hand, none of these will inherently be a master record of the others, so there isn't a clear way on how to make it relational/hierarchical.

I was thinking that adding a `"GroupID"` column might work, and then assign all of the names in a "set" to the same `GroupID`, but the `GroupID` field would have no other meaning other than grouping, and getting a set of nicknames will always require a nested query like:

```
SELECT Name FROM Nicknames WHERE GroupID = (SELECT GroupID FROM Nicknames WHERE Name = 'Beth')
```

Not to mention that both columns in the table will need to have their own separate indexes for this to work efficiently.

Am I missing something?  This seems like it should be easy, but I can't get my head around it today.

(I am using SQL Server, but the question is fairly generic so I didn't tag it as such).

Comment: Isn't "Elizabeth" inherently a "master" record for the others?

Comment: @derobert: "Mistress", I think, no?

Comment: Look them up and then do what with them? Are you trying to build some De-dupping software?

Comment: In this era I would feel very self-conscious about creating a column called Formal_Name which *I* populated. Anne isn't a more formal version of Ann... nor is Joann, Annabelle, Annabeth... etc See here. http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/dist.female.first these are Actual first names, not nicknames. There are people named Jack, even though it's also a nick for John. Which is why I asked what are you going to do with the "translations". If this is being used for a backend process like deduping then I get it, but I would just buy a component that already does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track.  And yes, you will need a subquery or a JOIN to get the results.

If it were me, rather than using an integer group ID I'd use the formal version of the name.  The trick is you must include a mapping from the formal name to the formal name.  So your values would look like:

```
 Name          FormalName
 ------------  -----------
 Elizabeth     Elizabeth
 Beth          Elizabeth
 Betsy         Elizabeth
```

Now, if the user gives you "Beth" you would do:

```
 SELECT NT2.Name FROM NameTable NT1 INNER JOING NameTable NT2
    ON NT2.FormalName = NT1.FormalName AND NT1.Name = 'BETH'
```

You can also create a view as follows:

```
 CREATE VIEW NameMapping (OriginalName, NickName) AS 
 SELECT NT1.Name, NT2.Name FROM NameTable NT1 INNER JOIN NameTable NT2
    ON NT2.FormalName = NT1.FormalName
```

and then

```
 SELECT NickName FROM NameMapping WHERE OriginalName = 'BETH'
```

(the optimizer should make this SELECT as efficient as the first one).

Comment: Which is the Master? George or Jorge? They are both fully proper (Formal_name) in their own language.

Comment: Doesn't matter, simply choose one (probably the language the system is written in).  The user is talking about diminutives in a single language, not i18n.  But the same scheme works just as well for translation.  Notice that the FormalName column is not returned in either of the queries, just the NickName (or synonym).  This works just as well with an integer GroupID (as originally suggested by the user) but seems harder to maintain to me.

Comment: I think that this might be the best way to go.  In some cases it might be difficult to pick out the 'master' record, but it appears that everything would work fine even if the master were selected 'incorrectly'.

Comment: Of course, I'm going to end up with a bit of a problem with: SELECT NickName FROM NameMapping WHERE OriginalName = 'PAT' (Patrick or Patricia as master records) and 'KRIS'... and 'JERRY'... and 'KIM' (an Asian male may be a bit offended if I offer up 'KIMBERLY' as a suggestion), but this gets me started.  Accepted!

Answer (score 1):

I like the example shown here

http://answers.google.com/answers/main?cmd=threadview&id=251498

As that avoids the problem of which is the more Formal name that Larry Lustig solution has. Unless you want to have each of the Nicknames as a FormalName also.

```
Group_no         Names
________         _____

1                Richard
1                Rick
1                Dick
1                Ric
2                Steve
2                Steven
2                Stephen
3                Ricky
3                Rick
3                Ric
```

I like this because if someone enterys  Rick it will show them all of Group 1 and Group 3 names.  But is someone enterys Ricky then they will not end up with unwanted names like Dick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that nickname1, nickname2, etc is bad practice.  I wouldn't suggest EVER using that unless you only need 2 and your 100% sure that will never change.

It seems to be like you DO have a master record here: the real name.  Basically, you can design the tables as follows:

```
Create Table Users(userID int, username varchar(20))
Create Table Nicknames(nicknameID int, name varchar(20), nickname(20))
```

Then for each of those nicknames in your examples, you'll need to insert a record.

```
INSERT INTO Nicknames(name, nickname) VALUES('Beth', 'Elizabeth')
INSERT INTO Nicknames(name, nickname) VALUES('Beth', 'Eliza')
etc...
```

Then your query to retrive them will be something like:

```
Select nickname from Nicknames where name = 'Beth'
```

You may be able to find a database with information like this online also, so that you don't have to build it from scratch.  Something like: http://www.peacockdata2.com/products/pdnickname/